# Python: Extend for loop operation to each row in matrix without using iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a piece of code like this:

```
a = Y[0]; b = Z[0]
print(a, b)
loss = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    k = len(a)-i
    loss += (2**(k-1))*np.abs(a[i]-b[i])
print(loss)
```

Where `Y` and `Z` are of dimensions `250 x 10` and each row is 10 bit binary value. For example, `print(a,b)` prints this: `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]`

Now I want to apply the two line function inside the for loop for corresponding rows between `Y` and `Z`. But I don't want to do something like this:

```
for j in range(Y.shape[0]):
    a = Y[j]; b = Z[j]
    loss = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        k = len(a)-i
        loss += (2**(k-1))*np.abs(a[i]-b[i])
    print(loss)
```

I am essentially trying to make a custom loss function in keras/tensorflow. And that for loop example doesn't scale for large tensor operations. How do I do it with some sort of batch matrix operation instead of for loops?

Comment: `to each pair of rows between Y and Z` - you are performing the operation only on corresponding pair of rows, right?

Comment: Do you want the final computed `loss` to be a vector (whose length is equal to number of pairs selected from `Y` and `Z`)? Or, do you want `loss` to be reduced further to a single scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
factor = 2**np.arange(Y.shape[1])[::-1]
loss = np.sum(factor * np.abs(Y-Z), axis=-1)
```

Comment: sorry i should have clarified in my post. I needed corresponding rows.

Comment: For example, if I were to do `Z = Y` then run your code, I should get 0.

Comment: @Jonathan -- Edited my answer accordingly. It's even more simplified now.

Comment: @Jonathan - I have now edited the answer to provide a vector of `250` loss values. Pls confirm after verifying if that's what you want.

Comment: Timing for your answer: `20.5 µs ± 4.21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`. Whereas timing for the approach I had suggested: `210 µs ± 32.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`. Kudos!

Comment: @anurag - Hope you don't mind if I convey a few thoughts under your answer, as comments.

Answer (score 1):

If only the inner loop needs to be made numpy parallelized:

```py
import numpy as np

for j in range(Y.shape[0]):
    a = Y[j]; b = Z[j]
    loss = 0
    """
    for i in range(len(a)):
        k = len(a)-i
        loss += (2**(k-1))*np.abs(a[i]-b[i])
    """
    k = np.arange(len(a), 0, -1)
    loss = np.sum(np.multiply(2**(k-1), np.abs(a-b)))
    print(loss)
```

**EDIT**

To make it even more numpy parallelized, use the following approach:

```py
import numpy as np

# This function computes loss for row pairs
def get_loss(row, sz):
    loss = 0
    k = np.arange(sz, 0, -1)
    loss = np.sum(np.multiply(2**(k-1), np.abs(row[:sz]-row[sz:])))
    return loss

# Sample input matrices
A = np.random.random((5, 10))
B = np.random.random((5, 10))

# Concatenate the input matrices
AB = np.concatenate((A, B), axis=1)

# apply the function on each row pair
result = np.apply_along_axis(get_loss, 1, AB, A.shape[1])

# result is a 1D array of the losses
print(result.shape)
```

Comment: Concatenation is a slightly expensive operation as it involves copying of the array data into a new memory location for a newly created array. Instead of concatenating, you could pass them as two separate arrays, and access them appropriately inside the function. (In any you seem to be accessing the two halves of the concatenated array separately inside the function)

Comment: I wanted to use `np.apply_along_axis`. without concat, the second matrx would need indexing, beating the purpose!